# Installer Wrappers for Executable Jar with Dependencies

Tags: java, installation, executable-jar

I've written a program in Java (executable JAR) and need to create an installer for it. The installer needs to have the following qualities:

1. Must work in Windows AND Mac environments.
2. Allows for the usual "Next -> Next -> Install" installer prompts. (Ease of use for customers)
3. Must allow exact placement of external dependencies.

Note (#3): Many of the external dependencies need to be placed in the same directory as the executable jar for the program to work correctly.

And it would be nice if it was easy to configure. It doesn't have to be free, if it costs a few bucks and is very simple, please include it.

Thanks.

EDIT: Please no "that's stupid, redesign" comments/answers. I didn't choose to make the program with external dependencies, it was specified by my employer for certain reasons. I make it their way or they find someone else who will.

Comment: *"Many of the external dependencies need to be placed in the same directory as the executable jar for the program to work correctly."*  Redesign the app. (is the best approach, I think).

Comment: @npe  JWS does not allow the deployer to specify that the 'external dependencies' are in the same location as the class files - in fact it would actively work against it.  They can be added to the run-time class-path easily, but not the 'same directory'.

Comment: I thought - if listed as a resource in the `jnlp` - they will by placed by the jar by JWS. I'm not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Andrew: This was how the program was specified to be created by my employer unfortunately, they want to be able to modify the program by swapping out some of the specific dependencies. Regardless, I have to keep it this way.

Comment: *"they want to be able to modify the program by swapping out some of the specific dependencies"*  If you can do that in the 'same directory', you can do it for any 'known and reproducible path'.  It is easier to create the latter, than determine the former.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't write up the specs, I make suggestions to my client. If they want it a certain way, even after I protest, that's the way I do it or they find someone else who will.

Comment: @npe  There are two slight subtleties that stuff it up though.  1) The archives might or might not still be archives.  It is configured by the user and not knwon to the app.  If running code were able to find the location of the class running it, that directory might be the 'top' of the JWS cahce, or a sub-directory based on the package name. 2) But much more importantly, code running in JWS cannot get the path on the local file-system by using the usual `CodeSource` trick.  Sun decided it was a security risk even for trusted code.  The source always points back to the server, even when cached

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Learning something new every day. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [IzPack](http://izpack.org/).
It's free, and allows for building installers for Windows and MacOS.
Not sure about the #3 requirement, but it's a installer, so you should be able to just feed it with files, and specify install paths for them.

Comment: +1 I was hoping you'd reinstate this answer.  So far it seems the only way to fulfill the spec. (that I think itself needs changing).  OK - not 'IzPack' exclusively, but a 'Java installer' of that general nature.

Comment: I was thinking this would be the installer I'd have to go with, IzPack is a good solution, just more complicated than I was hoping. ;)